# Android Facebook login redirect

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app where I am setting up facebook login for my users. I was testing out the scenario where the Facebook app isnät installed on the device, in which it redirects to another `Activity` where a dialog is opened and a `WebView` with the appropriate fields is shown. Once I login through this, it continues to the main page on my app. But the previous `WebView` activity still remains when I press back. Any idea how I can finish it from my main `Activity`?

EDIT: Posting the code of the function from where I call my DoLogin class.

```
public void doFacebookLogin(){

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                if(!loggedIn){              // loggedIn is a boolean value which checks if the authentication has been successful
                    if(session.isOpened()){

                        Log.d("FB", "is opened");

                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                                  OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(FacebookHandler.this);
                                  List<String> readPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
                                  readPermissions.add("email");
                                  openRequest.setPermissions(readPermissions);
                                  openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                                  //openRequest.setCallback();
                                  NewPermissionsRequest rp = new NewPermissionsRequest(FacebookHandler.this,readPermissions);

                                  session.requestNewReadPermissions(rp);

                                String accessToken = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();

                                DoLogin login = new DoLogin();
                                login.execute(accessToken);

                          }
                        });
                    }else{

                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Login error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        t.show();

                    }
                }
            }
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on button click where you opening link in `webview`

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(URL));
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Is this the case in which LoginButton is used? Cause I am not. I am using a Session.openActiveSession(this, true, Session.StatusCallback());